# Remove programs from Open With Other Application menu

Tags: unity, wine

Wine placed about 18 useless apps (most of them just repeat) into the Open With Other Application menu and they bother me because they are useless and interfere with the quick open with menu. How do I remove the applications from there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To clean Open With List for Wine applications, please carefully paste the following commands into a terminal:

```
rm -f ~/.local/share/mime/packages/x-wine*
rm -f ~/.local/share/applications/wine-extension*
rm -f ~/.local/share/icons/hicolor/*/*/application-x-wine-extension*
rm -f ~/.local/share/mime/application/x-wine-extension*
```

If you want to delete applications from the OpenWith list you have to edit the following file from command line and remove unneeded file associations.

```
/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache
```

If you added item by yourself, or you want to add new item you need to edit the following file from command line and remove unneeded file associations.

```
~/.local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache
```

You can also remove the corresponding .desktop files from ~/.local/share/applications where ~ is your home directory.

Comment: Thanks. Ill try it. I thought it would be something in the .local folder :)

Comment: i want to remove other stuff, which of the folders should be considered or do you know any apps taht help organize these things?

Comment: You want to remove other wine applications ?

Comment: ,no i want to remove other applications in the same open with window

Comment: Which desktop environment to you use ?

Comment: Gnome, unity, ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Check my updated answer.